# Calling the button.click() event from javascript doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button, click

I have the following source in aspx:

```
<div>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hidValue" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="hidButton" OnClick="hidButton_Click"    /> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ExtendPanel(PanelNumber) {
            var hidValue = document.getElementById('<%=hidValue.ClientID %>');
            hidValue.value = PanelNumber;

            document.getElementById('<%=hidButton.ClientID%>').fireEvent("onclick");
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

In my code behind, I have the following C# function declared:

```
protected void hidButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int PanelNumber = int.Parse(hidValue.Value);
    ... do something with PanelNumber ...
}
```

When I click on the button using the mouse, "hidButton_Click" function is normally executed.
However, when the javascript function ExtendPanel(PanelNumber) is executed, the click event seems to be fired, but the function is not executed.

Comment: fireEvent doesn't work in IE9 or greater. Why not just click?             `document.getElementById('<%=hidButton.ClientID%>').click();`

Comment: I have tried this. It still does not execute the click event.

Answer (score 4):

Replace this

```
document.getElementById('<%=hidButton.ClientID%>').fireEvent("onclick");
```

with

```
__doPostBack('hidButton','OnClick');
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't do the trick. I am using the same principle on other pages in my project as well, and they work perfectly.

Comment: you can also use this code..                                            var clickButton = document.getElementById("<%= hidButton.ClientID %>");
clickButton.click();

Comment: then u can submit the form using javascript and check the condition in page load if match then call the required function. code for submit the form is - document.getElementById('form').submit();

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
document.getElementById('<%=hidButton.ClientID%>').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one below

```
$('#<%=hidButton.ClientID%>').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issues and resolved to put

**OnClientClick="javascript:return true;"**